# Combobox doesn't show ArrayList on Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist

I'm new to swing, and I'm trying to show an Array data on a ComboBox, but for some reason whenever I add data to it, the ComboBox doesn't seem to refresh with the data inserted, even though if I run a test on console using a system.out inside the forEach, the data inserted on the ArrayList (it also shows on debug). Here's the mainMenu class:

```
package com.gui.main;

/* imports */

public class mainMenu {

    ArrayList<Instituicao> instituicoes = new ArrayList<Instituicao>();

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*...*/
    }

    public mainMenu() {
        initialize();
    }

    public void setComboboxInstituicao(JComboBox comboBox) {

        comboBox.removeAllItems();

        Vector<String> inst = new Vector<String>();

        if(!instituicoes.isEmpty()) {
            for(Instituicao i : instituicoes) {
                inst.add(i.getNomeInstituicao());
            }
        } else {
            inst.add("Select...");
        }

        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(inst));

        comboBox.setBounds(22, 120, 600, 33);
        frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);
    }

    private void initialize() {
        /*...*/

        // ComboBox

        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
        setComboboxInstituicao(comboBox);

        JLabel lblSelecioneUmaInstituio = new JLabel("Select an institution:");
        lblSelecioneUmaInstituio.setBounds(22, 93, 206, 15);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblSelecioneUmaInstituio);

        // Calls another window for data insert

        JButton btnNovaInstituio = new JButton("New Institution");
        btnNovaInstituio.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                adicionaInstituicao window = new adicionaInstituicao();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        /*...*/
    }
}
```

I used a setCombobox function to run each time the framework reloads, but it still not working.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  ..

Comment: .. Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 4) **It looks like the `comboBox` variable is being shadowed. I.E. Declared as an attribute of the class, only to be declared again as a local variable.**